# Need help on a query

Tags: sql, select

I have a table `employees` that looks like this:

```
Id Name Manager_Id
1  ABC   4
2  DEF   20
3  GHI   30
4  JKL   40
```

The below query does not return any results. I was expecting that it would return "JKL". What am I missing here?

```
select e1.Name from Employees e1 where e1.id = 
   (select e2.manager_id from employees e2 where e2.id = e1.id);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you break this query down from the outside in, you're expecting to find a record where `e1.id = e2.manager_id` but also where `e2.id = e1.id`. In other words, you're querying for a record where `id = manager.id`, which simply does not exist.

What I assume you're trying to do is select all the records where the `id` exists as a `manager_id` in the table.
This can be done much more simply with an `in` operator:

```
SELECT name
FROM   employees
WHERE  id IN (SELECT manager_id FROM employees)
```

Comment: Thank you Mureinik. That explanation helped.

Answer (score 2):

use `in`, not `=` :

```
select e1.Name from Employees e1 where e1.id IN 
   (select e2.manager_id from employees e2 where e2.id = e1.id);
```

The `=` operator is for testing if scalars are the same. `IN` tests set membership.

Comment: Using IN is still not working. In OR = does not throw any error but does not return any result.